# User control used in user control

Tags: controls

I made user control(example - User control 1) in my project and successfully added to my toolbox.

After that  I use same user control (which I already added to my toolbox - User control 1) for another new user control (User control 2).

I follow same procedure for adding User control 2 in my toolbox but the User control 2 do not shows at my toolbox. I do not receive any errors. Using 2008 version.

Pls. help.